# Overdraw mean points in grouped boxplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a grouped boxplot with ggplot2 like this

```
p <- qplot(factor(cyl), mpg, data=mtcars, geom="boxplot", fill=factor(gear))
```

and I want to overdraw the mean points. I've tried this

```
p+ stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="point")
```

but, I don't get the mean points over the boxes of each group. 
[image]

What should I do to get this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should set position to `position_dodge()` and `width` to 0.75 - so points will be placed in the same way as boxplots.

```
qplot(factor(cyl), mpg, data=mtcars, geom="boxplot", fill=factor(gear)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", 
             geom="point",position=position_dodge(width=0.75))
```