# Boxplot with mean points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a boxplot with `ggplot2` and trying (without any success) put the mean points of each variable on it. Can someone point what is wrong?

A reproducible example:

```
data <- data.frame(id=1:5000, Estimativa0=gl(5, 1000), NM.Intra1=rnorm(5000, rep(rnorm(5, 0, 4), each=1000)), NM.Entre2=rnorm(5000, rep(rnorm(5, 0, 4), each=1000)), SPADE3=rnorm(5000, rep(rnorm(5, 0, 4), each=1000)),  NCI4=rnorm(5000, rep(rnorm(5, 0, 4), each=1000)))
data <- reshape(data, direction='long', varying=list(c("NM.Intra1", "NM.Entre2", "SPADE3", "NCI4")), idvar=c('id', 'Estimativa0'), times=c("NM.Intra1", "NM.Entre2", "SPADE3", "NCI4"), timevar='Método')
levels(data$Estimativa0) <- c('Est 1', 'Est 2', 'Est 3', 'Est 4', 'Est 5', 'Est 6')
p <- ggplot(data, aes(Método, NM.Intra1))
p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Estimativa0))) + ylab('Vício') + xlab('Método') + scale_fill_discrete("Estatística") + ggtitle('Gráfico maluco da Greice') + geom_hline(yintercept=0)
p
```

The first try was:

```
medias <- with(data, aggregate(data.frame(Media=NM.Intra1), by=list(Estimativa0=Estimativa0, Método=Método), FUN=mean))
p + geom_point(aes(x=Método, y=Media), data=medias, shape=2)
```

But it ploted all points in the same 'vertical line'. I tried the solution pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532978/overdraw-mean-points-in-grouped-boxplot-with-ggplot2), but fail too:

```
p + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="point", position=position_dodge(width=0.75), shape=2)
```

So, what I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the mean of each `Método`-`Estimativa0` combination. In that case, you need to tell `stat_summary` to group by `Estimativa0` as well; right now, the mapping is only done in `geom_boxplot` and is thus not inherited by `stat_summary`.

So, delete this:

```
aes(fill=factor(Estimativa0))
```

And put `fill=factor(Estimativa0)` in the initial mapping:

```
aes(Método, NM.Intra1, fill=factor(Estimativa0))
```

You'll end up with this:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(Método, NM.Intra1, fill=factor(Estimativa0)))
p <- p + geom_boxplot() + ylab('Vício') + xlab('Método') + scale_fill_discrete("Estatística") + ggtitle('Gráfico maluco da Greice') + geom_hline(yintercept=0)
p + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="point", position=position_dodge(width=0.75), shape=2)
```

which produces this:

[image]