# Boxplot overlaid on dot plot + means, means in wrong position

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using advice given in    [Overdraw mean points in grouped boxplot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532978/overdraw-mean-points-in-grouped-boxplot-with-ggplot2/28236658#28236658) I tried

```
FEV <- expand.grid(sex=c('female', 'male'), smoke=c('no', 'yes'),
                   reps=1:5)
set.seed(1)
FEV$fev <- runif(nrow(FEV), 1, 4)
ggplot(FEV, aes(x=smoke, y=fev, color=sex)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha=.5, width=.2) + # remove width to overlay boxes on pts
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=5, size=2, 
               position=position_dodge(width=.2)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', position='dodge') +
  xlab('') + ylab(expression(FEV[1])) + coord_flip()
```

[image: Dot plot with overlaid box plot and means]

The means are not placed quite correctly in the vertical sense. Guidance welcomed.  Note: I like having the box plots between the two sets of dots; that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help for ?position_dodge just says that dodging things with different widths is tricky - I usually tweak this manually. Trying a few values, it looks like you want the points to take a dodge width that is 3/4 of the boxplot width but I don't know why or if that holds for other geoms. I would try changing the width for the stat_summary call to 0.15

Comment: isnt the issue that the mean points have had there position tweaked (dodged) but the boxplots have not, and so are not placed in the centre of the boxplots. This can be fixed by dodging the boxplots an equal amount.